# Change the encoding of FileReader's result to UTF8

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a small function that retrieves the contents of an uploaded text file.

```
upload() {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        console.log(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(this.file);
}
```

It works fine when the encoding of the file uploaded is UTF8, but in my case (using an UTF16_LE encoded file) it adds random spacing between characters, changes some to something different, or transforms them to chinese.

My question is, how can I convert `reader.result` to UTF8 without having to manually re-save the file itself to UTF8?

Comment: Note that you don't want to convert it to UTF-8, but to read read it in the correct encoding (it will actually convert it to a DOMString (UTF-16)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileReader.readAsText()` function [has on optional `encoding` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) that you can use to specify the encoding to use for the returned data.